# Text on usercontrol gets scrambled after navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a WPF application that's fairly standard. I have a window, with a navigation Frame inside, where I load Pages. All of my pages have a similar template with a User Control in the bottom right, which is the nav menu.

Occasionally (and I can not detect a pattern to it) some of the TextBlocks in the usercontrol will get garbled, either stating a fully qualified class, another string, or nothing at all.

This is what it's supposed to look like:
[image]

This is what it looked like a minute ago:
[image]

The XAML code for the userControl is

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="spNavigation" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,18,0">
        <TextBlock Text="N....N - 5" MouseUp="TextBox_MouseUp" Name="tbStockNav" Style="{StaticResource MenuDefault}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Orders" MouseUp="TextBox_MouseUp" Name="tbPatientsNav" Style="{StaticResource MenuDefault}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Recalls" MouseUp="TextBox_MouseUp" Name="tbRecallNav" Style="{StaticResource MenuDefault}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Messages" MouseUp="TextBox_MouseUp" Name="tbMessagesNav" Style="{StaticResource MenuDefault}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Users" MouseUp="TextBox_MouseUp" Name="tbUsersNav" Style="{StaticResource MenuDefault}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Home" MouseUp="TextBox_MouseUp" Name="tbHomeNav" Style="{StaticResource MenuDefault}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

And a bit of relevant code behind for loading a new page. It's very straightforward, and I can't for the life of me figure out why my text is getting garbled.

```
private void TextBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = (sender as TextBlock).Text;
        openWindow(text);
    }

private void openWindow(string text)
    {
        NavigationService navigationService = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);

        if (text == "Users")
        {
            navigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/UsersPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

I'm curious to understand how to fix it, but also why this is happening.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The textboxes are never modified, except for the background color and padding, from a dependencyProperty:

```
                int offset = Convert.ToInt16(Application.Current.TryFindResource("MenuOffset"));
            activeTB.Background = BACKGROUND_COLOR;
            activeTB.Padding = new Thickness(12,12+offset,12,12);
            activeTB.Margin = new Thickness(0,-1*offset,0,0);
```

The style is rather simple...

```
<Style x:Key="MenuDefault" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="19"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12"/>
</Style>
```

It Almost looks like a pointer issue, where it's going to the wrong object to get the string value to display.

Comment: I have yet to use a `Frame` and `Pages` in one of the many applications I've written... I wonder what's considered standard... I guess you're not using an MVVM Framework like Caliburn.Micro or the like? All that codebehind feels so procedural. In your case I'd first do a project wide search for _tbMessagesNav_ and see if its `Text` gets altered somewhere, then with VS's Visual Tree Debugger take a lookt at that particular TextBlock and at last do a search for `.Text =` and see if there's something altering your `Text` property. What you experience is not normal.

Comment: I'm not using any MVVM framework on this project. The textblock.Text property is never modified, which is where I'm faltering. I even tried renaming textblock names, thinking perhaps they were being referenced somewhere else, somehow, but it didn't do any good.

"What you experience is not normal" Hence why I'm here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking a closer look at your MenuDefault style, and maybe post it here.  Are there any Bindings or Triggers in there?  This behavior could be expected if you were Binding the Text property to an object of that type.  Otherwise, is there anything else in the xaml or code-behind that references those TextBlocks?  From what you have posted, I don't see any reason why the TextBlock's Text property would be anything other than what you have specified.

To better debug the issue, consider installing [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and navigating the Visual Tree to that TextBlock.  You can then inspect the properties for the TextBlock.

Comment: I downloaded and tried using Snoop, and the text property was set to what it was displaying, however, I have no idea how it's getting like that. Is there a way to see in Snoop what is setting the property? There aren't any bindings on it, it appears to be manually set.

Comment: Snoop doesn't show who is setting the property.  But if you are setting the Text property manually, there are only so many ways for that text to change.  If you temporarily remove the Style and the Name, does the text still change?  Does your TextBox_MouseUp method in your code-behind do anything with the sender parameter?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your edit.  I don't know why it's failing -- your posted code looks ok.  I know it isn't the solution that you are looking for, but an MVVM approach would be easier to debug, and most would consider it a better design approach.  In this case, instead of using a TextBlock, you could use a Button (you can style it to look the same).  That button could implement a Command pattern instead of MouseUp events.  And the content could be a bound to a property on the View Model, which could be easily debugged by placing a breakpoint on the property setter.